# How do i build for custom types in visual studios 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, custom-build-step

I knew how to do it in older versions. I have several files that are .abc and .xyz. If the file has been changed i'd like to run my build script then build my C++ files.

How do i do it in VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are "custom build rules" not "custom build steps".

VS2010 no longer has UI to define custom build rules, but the functionality is still there; now you need to write several xml files by hand.

The simplest way is to open a VS2008 project and let the wizard migrate the stuff, then you can examine the resulting project to see how it looks like.

There is little information on the web, but if you search for "custom build rules" you should find some blog posts from Microsoft people, for example [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/21/quick-help-on-vs2010-custom-build-rule.aspx) gives several examples.